# Index text file using apache solr

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I want to index text files in solr. However my data is large so I want to index it paragraph by paragraph. Using apache tika I am not able to do it. Can someone help me do it using DataImportHandler. I am currently using Solr-6.5.1

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: How did you attempt to index files now? Can you preprocess the files into separate paragraphs before submitting them? How do you want the documents structured in Solr? How large are the text files? What error did you get?

Comment: Presently I am indexing the files using curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=1&commit=true" -F myFile=@files/sample.txt and I have data in the paragraphs. The functionality that I want is that while searching in solr it should not give me the whole content of the document. Instead I want to reduce the search result to the paragraph in which the query keyword is present in.

Comment: Re "How do you want the documents structured in Solr?" I want them paragraph by paragraph.
Re "How large are the text files?" Large enough that I can't find the keyword I want to search in the document